# Use gradient image or pure css in navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, gradient

I use bootstrap and want to change the color of the navbar with some gradient and transparency (see attached picture). Should I use the image with the code

```
background: url(../img/nav-bg.png) repeat-x;
```

or should I convert it to css and use pure css?

How is browser support?

It's a little bit easier to change the color and size if it is pure CSS, but I get a lot more code for the same result.

Do you suggest using pure CSS or image as the background color to the navbar?

[image: Navbar image]

Comment: can you give us a fiddle please? or at least some code???

Comment: Use background color instead of background image.

Comment: @SayedRafeeq I just flagged it as a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason to use image for that. You can see the table with the support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-repeating-gradients).

[image]

Also, the default background for navbar in Bootstrap is:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, 0%, #f8f8f8, 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f8f8f8 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #f8f8f8 100%);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use pure CSS because it makes your code more flexible: In the future you could need only gradient or trasparency,so you will change only that property whereas using a background image you will change the image (bad solution). In addition,using a bg image could make displaying problems if run your code on small screens.
For browser support you can verify it on w3schools

Answer (score -2):

I suggest that you use both!

```
.gradient {
  
  /* Fallback (could use .jpg/.png alternatively) */
  background-color: red;

  /* SVG fallback for IE 9 (could be data URI, or could use filter) */
  background-image: url(fallback-gradient.svg); 

  /* Safari 4, Chrome 1-9, iOS 3.2-4.3, Android 2.1-3.0 */
  background-image:
    -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(red), to(#f06d06));
  
  /* Safari 5.1, iOS 5.0-6.1, Chrome 10-25, Android 4.0-4.3 */
  background-image:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, #f06d06);

  /* Firefox 3.6 - 15 */
  background-image:
    -moz-linear-gradient(left, red, #f06d06);

  /* Opera 11.1 - 12 */
  background-image:
    -o-linear-gradient(left, red, #f06d06);

  /* Opera 15+, Chrome 25+, IE 10+, Firefox 16+, Safari 6.1+, iOS 7+, Android 4.4+ */
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, red, #f06d06);

}
```

additionally inline your image instead of having it as a url (use base64 in css) this way you will skip the overhead of loading additional resources from the server.

## Update

performance wise, having an image instead is of a css gradient is much more efficient on for rendering. the overhead of an image is a server request so you can inline it in base64 to avoid that.

with simple css gradients the difference is minor, hence using css is always recommended in that case. try to use both if you really want it to work everywhere. if you want to punish old-browser users (which i recommend) use a background color as a fallback.

Comment: people who downvoted my answer, can you please clarify the reason?